# How to override grappelli js file in django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm using grappelli and I have two files in it I need to modify:

```
admin/js/SelectBox.js
admin/js/SelectFilter2.js
```

I thought it would be a good idea to put it into my app static directory:

```
my_app/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js
my_app/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js
```

But whenever I try `./manage.py collectstatic` files from my_app are overrided by original files from grappelli, however I need it vice versa.

I need just to add several strings in this files into existing functions, so I can't handle it within a new js files and include into Media class ( from my point of view ).

Is there any way to override grappelli files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement that, I had to order the installed apps in settings.py to put grappelli after my app, cause while collecting static files, if there are multiple files with the same name Django will pick the first one it finds. What that means is, unless you've changed [STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_FINDERS), files inside folders in STATICFILES_DIRS will have the highest priority.